# android webview open google maps app

Tags: android

i have an android web view and it displays the site correctly but when i press a link with geo data i get an the following error:
"webiste is unavailable the website geo:48.9596430,9.125670?q=48.959630,9.125670 couldnt be loaded"

net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

when i open the same site on my chrome browser it opens my google maps with the desired cordinates.. now im windering why my webview doesnt do it :S

here is the webiew code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    /**
     * WebViewClient subclass loads all hyperlinks in the existing WebView
     */
    public class GeoWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // When user clicks a hyperlink, load in the existing WebView
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * WebChromeClient subclass handles UI-related calls
     * Note: think chrome as in decoration, not the Chrome browser
     */
    public class GeoWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        @Override
        public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin,
                                                       GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
            // Always grant permission since the app itself requires location
            // permission and the user has therefore already granted it
            callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
        }
    }

    WebView mWebView;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        // Brower niceties -- pinch / zoom, follow links in place
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new GeoWebViewClient());
        // Below required for geolocation
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new GeoWebChromeClient());

        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.bda-bawue.de");
    }



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // Pop the browser back stack or exit the activity
        if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        }
        else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

and this link should be opened:

```
<a href="geo:48.959630, 9.125670?q=48.959630, 9.125670">
```

permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

do i have to change the link for an android web view or whats the point?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

May be this help.

```
@Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // When user clicks a hyperlink, load in the existing WebView
            if(url.contains("geo:")) {
                Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse(url);
                Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
                mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
                if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                      startActivity(mapIntent);
                }
            return true;
        }  
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: ok this works but when i press the back button i get the error page again is there a wa to cpletely skip this page and just open the map?

Comment: this means what it does now is the following: i press the link and the app tries to open in inside the web view i gues..then the google maps app is starting. When i press back my own app opens again and displays the same page as written above.. what i would need now is to skip the part where the app tries to open the link itself

Comment: Happy to help. You can use `url.startsWith("geo:")` insteadof `url.contains("geo:")` and mark the answer as correct.

Comment: I changed if(url.contains("geo:")) { to if(url.contains("google.com/maps")) { and it works great!

Comment: Don't forget to add the permission 'android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES'. This didn't work without it.

Answer (score 6):

```
if(url.contains("https://www.google.com/maps/"))
{
  Uri IntentUri = Uri.parse(url);
  Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, IntentUri);
  mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");

  if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
     startActivity(mapIntent);
  }
  return true;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want the user to use only google maps, you can try the code below.

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if(url.contains("geo:")){
        view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(url)));
        return true;
            else
                {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
                }

    }
}
```